# Can I add a new column without rewriting an entire file?

Tags: apache-arrow

I've been experimenting with Apache Arrow.  I have used the column oriented memory mapped files for many years.  In the past, I've used a separate file for each column.  Arrow seems to like to store everything in one file.  Is there a way to add a new column without rewriting the entire file?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is probably no.

Arrow's in-memory format & libraries support this.  You can add a chunked array to a table by just creating a new table (this should be zero-copy).

However, it appears you are talking about storing tables in files.  None of the common file formats in use (parquet, csv, feather) support partitioning a table in this way.

Keep in mind, if you are reading a parquet file, you can specify which column(s) you want to read and it will only read the necessary data.  So if your goal is only to support individual column retrieval/query then you can just build one large table with all your columns.